# Multivariate Linear Regression using sklearn not matching the Normal equation of Cost Function

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have to fit my data to a multivariate linear Model. But sklearn.linear_model is producing different answers than those predicted by Normal Equation.here is the code for both:

```
   x=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
   y=np.arange(3,6).reshape(3,1)
   x=np.insert(x,0,1,axis=1)
   def normal(X,y):
       return np.dot(np.dot(linalg.pinv(np.dot(X.T,X)),X.T),y)

   normal(x,y)
   >>> [[ 0.4375 ]
       [-0.59375]
       [-0.15625]
       [ 0.28125]
       [ 0.71875]]
   from sklearn import linear_model
   reg=linear_model.LinearRegression()
   reg.fit(x,y)
   reg.coef_
   >>> [[ 0.    ,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625]]
```

Is my code correct?

Comment: I don't think that `normal` function is correct. `np.linalg.pinv` returns the pseudoinverse of its input, which can be computed as `np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T)`. So you're doing some combination of the inverse and pseudoinverse. `normal` should `return np.linalg.pinv(X).dot(y)`.

Comment: It is included in case of a non invertible matrix. It does not affect the answer in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that you are including the intercept term in your data matrix.  By default, the `LinearRegression` class of scikit-learn automatically finds the intercept term, so you do not need to insert the column of 1s in your matrix:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
x=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
y=np.arange(3,6).reshape(3,1)    
reg=linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x,y)
```

We thus get for the coefficients and intercept terms:

```
In [32]: reg.coef_
Out[32]: array([[ 0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625]])

In [33]: reg.intercept_
Out[33]: array([ 2.625])
```

We can verify that we get the correct output by doing a dot product between each row of the matrix and the coefficients, and add the intercept term at the end

```
In [34]: x.dot(reg.coef_.T) + reg.intercept_
Out[34]:
array([[ 3.],
       [ 4.],
       [ 5.]])
```

Now if you want to **specifically** match what the normal equation gives you, that's fine and you can insert the column of ones.  You will however need to **disable** finding the intercept as you have manually inserted in a feature that would do that for you.

Therefore:

```
x=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
y=np.arange(3,6).reshape(3,1)
x=np.insert(x,0,1,axis=1)
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
reg.fit(x,y)
```

By doing this, we now get for our coefficients:

```
In [37]: reg.coef_
Out[37]: array([[ 0.4375 , -0.59375, -0.15625,  0.28125,  0.71875]])
```

This matches with the output of the normal equation.